# rqt_plot not plotting one signal; rostopic echo works

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to plot 2 signals: desired velocity and current velocity. Both come from a `Twist`, and I want to plot `/linear/x`. I try with `rqt_plot` and it can successfully plot the desired velocity, but not the current velocity.

Please have a look here:
https://imgur.com/a/bTqXF

However I can see the topic is being correctly published with `rostopic echo`:

```
$ rostopic echo /current_velocity/twist/linear/x
1.7227491072e-08
---
1.7227491072e-08
---
5.7998790784e-07
---
6.097357376e-07
---
5.9487299872e-07
```

What's the problem?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270754/rqt_plot-not-plotting-one-signal;-rostopic-echo-works/) by [carlosgalvezp](https://answers.ros.org/users/31869/carlosgalvezp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2017-09-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that `/current_velocity` did NOT have a `stamp` in the `header`. After adding it it works perfectly!

---

Originally posted by [carlosgalvezp](https://answers.ros.org/users/31869/carlosgalvezp/) with karma: 46 on 2017-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1